# Getting rid of animations left by removed 3dObjects in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, typed-arrays

I have a threejs r.67 application where I load skinned meshes(from sea3d) with vary large animations. tens of thousands of frames. When I remove one of the meshes and try to load a new one, I get OOM errors for recursive function. I don't have any recursive functions other than a render. I have been using the chrome dev tools to create heap snapshots, and I am seeing that the actual animation arrays are not being removed when the meshes are. Is there a way to remove the animation arrays so that I am not getting the OOM?

Here is a jsFiddle of what I am working with. You can load the different sea files using the Load Strength and Load Reflex buttons. After alternatively loading the files you will get an OOM. They take a bit to load, but wait until one is loaded before you load the next.

https://jsfiddle.net/DezOnlyOne/porsu3cd/20/

The animated files are loaded using the `loadPatient()` function

Comment: This is a pretty vague question... I can only guess that your animation manager (e.g., TWEEN.js, AnimTaskMgr.js, etc) is keeping a list of these objects around for periodic updating. You'll need to flush that list, so that the brower's garbage collector can discard them. As long as something in your app maintains a pointer to data, it will linger (and accumulate).

Comment: I am using sea3d which, from what I can tell, does not have any type of animation manager. When the mesh is loaded from the sea3d file, the skinned mesh has an array of animations from the artist export. This allows me just to call the animation by name.

Sorry about the vagueness of the question. I am not as well versed on the inner workings of sea3d or threejs. I have been able to use them pretty effectively until now. I agree that there must be a list of animations somewhere that is still hanging around, but I have no idea where to start looking.